# can't write data to realtime database firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue writing data to my realtime database in firebase. My setup is as following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  val actionBar: ActionBar = supportActionBar!!
  actionBar.hide()
  val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
  val myRef: DatabaseReference = database.getReference("Course")
  Timber.d(myRef.toString() + " hello there")
  myRef.setValue("testUser2")
}
```

And the console prints the path to my database:

> 2021-02-27 09:49:39.137 18688-18688/com.cpen391.flappyBird.moduleDemoApp D/SignUpActivity:    https://flappybird-7dea8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Course hello there

It seems like the connection to my database is all right but it just doesn't update the data:

[image]

I'm getting confused here, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the user have permission to write to the database? You can detect this in code, by listening to the completion of the `setValue` call. See for an example: https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75

Comment: i've tried to call addOnCompleteListener with Log.d in it , but nothing gets printed. the rules are set to be true.for both read and write btw.

Comment: If the completion handler never gets called, that means the call never completes on the server. Are you sure the device has a stable internet conneciton?

Comment: You are damn right my friend! The problem is internet in China doesn't have access to the outside world... no wonder it never completes the request..............

Comment: Good to hear that explains what you're seeing.    If you [enable disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence), you may be able to get a pretty decent initial developer experience, as Firebase will then persist the pending writes to the local disk. You just won't be able to synchronize to other clients.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Check if the write is rejected by the server, by attaching a completion listener as shown here: https://gist.github.com/puf/4a94a01e3c2510298ee46d0a7f90ab75
2. If the completion handler is never called, that means the call never completes on the server. Check if you have a stable internet connection that can reach the Firebase servers.
3. If indeed you have a connection problem to the servers, you can [enable disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence) to get a pretty decent initial developer experience, as Firebase will then persist the pending writes to the local disk. You just won't be able to synchronize to other clients.